# How to plot a segmentation mask, bounding box from given annotation values?

Tags: image, image-segmentation, image-masking

I have some images and an annotation file (.json) which contains the information of the area, image_id, segmentation points, bounding box points for every image. I would like to plot the segmentation mask and the bounding box on my input image using the annotation values. The annotation looks like this,

{"segmentation": [[389, 1065, 729, 1071, 737, 617, 397, 611]],"area": 11511.253450000006,"iscrowd": 0,"image_id": 1000,"bbox": [389, 611, 349, 461],"category_id": 1,"id": 1269164}

How to plot the segmentation on an image from the given annotation?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You seem to have omitted the corresponding image.